# Prevent toggling overwrite mode in Spacemacs or VI

Tags: vi

I hate the overwrite mode in VI.  I never actually want to overwrite, I just want to hit insert to confirm I am in Insert mode before typing, regardless of what state I was in previously, without worrying I may be toggling overwrite mode instead.

Is there a way to configure vi to never toggle to overwrite mode?  So the insert key toggles insert mode always?

I'm using Spacemacs so if someone knows how to do this in Spacemacs that would be best, but failing that if I can get the VI syntax I'm sure I can figure out how to add vi configuration to my Spacemacs config file (I'm pretty new to Spacemacs right now).

Comment: Since it's not a question about Unix or Linux, I'd recommend asking it on [vi and vim SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) or [Emacs SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/), although if I were you, I would go first to irc and ask there (e.g. freenode). Also remember that cross-posting is bad, so if you go somewhere else, delete the question here(or ask mod to move it)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to Replace Mode. I do not have VI in front of me to test this out. Try if it works for you:

```
function s:ForbidReplace()
    if v:insertmode isnot# 'i'
        call feedkeys("\<Insert>", "n")
    endif
endfunction
augroup ForbidReplaceMode
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter  * call s:ForbidReplace()
    autocmd InsertChange * call s:ForbidReplace()
augroup END
```

This script just flips Replace mode back to Insert. Reference link [here](http://www.ronaldpringadi.com/archives/customize-your-vim-editor-using-vimrc/).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using your `insert` key on your keyboard?  Just press `i`.  (It will never switch you to replace mode.  Worst case it will type the letter "i" and you can press backspace.)

Also, down at the bottom of your `vi` screen will be a little status bar that says "INSERT" when you are in insert mode.

---

Emacs and `vi` are *very* different, so it's kind of bizarre to see a question asking for a solution equally workable on either.

---

If you are primarily using insert mode for `vi` you may want to [learn more about Normal Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/5419599).